# Facing file get html error

Tags: php, error-handling, file-get-contents

I am getting the below error while triggering the file with crone jobs, while it doesn't show any error with manual triggering. Please help whats the logic behind this error. Thanks

> Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in **/home/afghannewscom/public_html/auto/MainProject.php** on line **35**

Comment: $OuterLink = file_get_html('http://www.khaama.com/');
$link = $OuterLink -> find('div[class=latest] ul li a');
echo $link = $link[0]->href;

$filename = 'Latest.txt';
$link_in = file_get_contents($filename);

Comment: Please edit your original post to add the error there, not in comments.

Comment: Here is the error : Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function find() on a non-object in <b>/home/afghannewscom/public_html/auto/MainProject.php</b> on line <b>35</b><br />

Comment: Getting problem in file_get_html() thats the line 35

Answer (score 0):

Look at the file `MainProject.php` on line 35 (in editor) and see whats the problem.
the variable `$OuterLink` is not an object. you may have a look at its definition line.

Comment: This is Line 35: $OuterLink = file_get_html('khaama.com/');

Comment: Can anyone tell me why the file_get_url() not working with CRONE Jobs while its ok when triggered manually.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar issue with cronjobs (PHP errors in cronjobs only, running file via browser was fine). The error was caused by incorrect server configuration (it was a shared server, so I couldn't change it). In my case, the fix was pretty easy - I changed cronjob from "php -q /some_file.php" to "curl http://somedomain.com/some_file.php" (you can also use lynx or wget command instead of curl)

Comment: I guess it also worked for me, please let me know what does it mean? curl: (3) <url> malformed     I got this in mail instead of error

Comment: Something wrong with URL (filename). What about this? "wget -O /dev/null http://www.yourdomain.com/some_file.php"